# Is there an effective way to rebin a large array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, histogram, binning

Background: I have large samples with histogram of counts for different frequency bins. The frequency bins for different samples are not identical, but are in similar range of a standard value. Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
frequency_standard = np.array([1, 3, 5, 7])
```

I have a gigantic collection of frequency samples and respective number counts at different two dimensional location. example purpose:

```
frequency_of_samples = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],[1.4,3.5, 4.6, 5.8],
                                 [2, 3.5, 5.6, 6.8]])
data_of_samples = np.array([[10, 14, 52, 12], [12, 32, 53, 21], 
                            [23, 54, 26, 13]])
```

Now I would like to rebin `data_of_samples` to `frequency_standard`, instead of `frequency_of_samples`. I would like to have a fast numpy method that would achieve this. My start is the following: first find the index of `frequency_of_samples` in the `frequency_standard`:

```
bin_index = np.digitize(frequency_of_samples, frequency_standard)
```

At this point I basically need to have a clean array to dump the number counts:

```
binned_data = np.zeros(data_of_samples.shape)
```

And cumulatively add the number from `data_of_samples` at `bin_index` to `binned_data`. This part is not working, and the following code does not make any sense, but I would like to have something like this:

```
binned_data[bin_index] += data_of_samples[bin_index]
```

Could anyone suggest me how to fix the last step? I would also welcome any other efficient solutions.

Comment: It is not numpy, but I have used pandas.cut method to create bins, then you can use the groupby method to calculate the average of all values in a bin, min, max or whatever statistic you want, or simply count the number of observations that land in the bin. I started off looking into the np.digitize function but ended up in a similar position of trying to calculate statistics for the samples in each bin. I can share my code if you want to see a working example.

Comment: @RobertMilletich I would really appreciate if you could share with me your code.

Comment: Sorry about the delay, on my github https://github.com/rmill040/citrees/blob/203daf4259d1acd72142416e60ae89ce86fa143f/citrees/scorers.py#L249 the function approx_wdcor is doing a weighted distance correlation by first binning a large data set and calculating the correlation with the average values in each bin. Let me know if you have any questions. Hopefully it should help you see how pandas can be used...this is some research I'm working on...I'll clean up the code later on